# Vim ruby identation

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm learning Vim and need to do the following:
Suppose I typed this:

```
class MyClass
private
end
```

After typing the `gg=G` I want the `private` to remain at the level with the class declaration, like this:

```
class MyClass
private
end
```

But it looks wrong (indent moves `private` to the right):

```
class MyClass
  private
end
```

How i can add custom rule for autoidentation of private?

Comment: [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) does not think so

Comment: @LazyNick7 what does RuboCop say?

Comment: Rubocop would disagree with you, you should be indenting `public`/`private` one level: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#indent-public-private-protected

Comment: Honestly yes I would never use this indentation he mentiones in the question. But maybe he has a reason for that. And even if he hasn't one, it still is a perfectly acceptable question in SO terms, isn't it? So it is nice to inform him that you wouldn't do that, but why the downvote? (This is not a critic, I am honestly interested to hear if there is a valid reason for a downvote)

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable, well written question. I'm sorry you have been downvoted simply because people disagree with your indentation style (??!!)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already mentioned, vim uses the recommended indentation:
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#indent-public-private-protected

However, if you want to change it, you can by setting a custom `indentexpr`

```
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal indentexpr=YourCustomFunction()
```

However writing such a function wil be a lot of work. Better go with the sane function your vim already uses and keep it to the official recommendation.

P.S. Rubocop has nothing against it, the error you get probably refers to an useless `private` statement because there is no function afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to keep the access modifier at the level of the class declaration, you can get Vim to respect that by putting this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:ruby_indent_access_modifier_style = 'outdent'
```

This is a configuration setting coming from Vim's ruby support, vim-ruby ([documentation](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/doc/vim-ruby.txt#L65)).

Note that this will only work with a recent enough Vim version. I'm not quite sure which, but, if it doesn't work for you, install the [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) plugin manually, like an ordinary plugin -- this'll give you access to the latest runtime files, including this setting (which might be a mixed blessing, there's currently some oddness around heredoc highlighting).

Comment: Didn't know about that one. If it works for you, this is way better than my solution with a custom `indentexpr` (way easier for sure).